# Confirmation about what DbContext.Set<T> is

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am seeking confirmation about what `DbContext.Set<T>` returns.

Say, for example, I had 2 classes:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TEntity> GetSet<TEntity>() where TEntity: class => Set<TEntity>(); 

}
```

If `contextInstance = new MyContext();`, does `contextInstance.MyEntities` return the EXACTLY the same `DbSet` as `contextInstance.GetSet<MyEntity>()` ?

Comment: You can use `Object.ReferenceEquals(set1, set2)` to find out.

Comment: @PeterB, or is it Confucius? ;-) Thanks - That completely slipped my mind!